# Swift Custom Function Availability within Extension

Tags: swift

I want to write a custom function, that should be available throughout the whole Swift Application. When I use an extension, I need to extent a certain class. But what if I want to write a custom function, that should be available in all classes? Where do I have to put it?

This is the function I want to make available:

```
extension MapViewController {
    func calculateDistanceToAED(latitude latitude: Double, longitude: Double) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let currentLocation: CLLocation = self.currentLocation
        let aedLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

        return currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(aedLocation)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give more details about what the function is for?

Comment: just added to the question

Comment: I would argue that you don't need to do this at all.  There are answers here that tell you how to do what you're asking to do, but I wouldn't let them pass a code review.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is just a global function I believe:

```
func calculateDistanceToAED(currentLocation:CLLocation, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) -> CLLocationDistance {
    let aedLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    return currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(aedLocation)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use global functions in Swift like -

```
public struct MyGolobalFunctions {
    public static func calculateDistanceToAED(latitude latitude: Double, longitude: Double, currentLocation: CLLocation) -> CLLocationDistance {
        let aedLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        return currentLocation.distanceFromLocation(aedLocation)
    }
}
```

**To Call GlobalFunction**

```
  let currentLocation = CLLocation()
  MyGolobleFunctions.calculateDistanceToAED(latitude: 75.22, longitude: 73.22, currentLocation: currentLocation)
```

Comment: how would be the approach to create a global function?

Comment: you function is depend on the class property self.currentLocation so It can't be global function. According to me global functions are those functions which will only process or calculate results only for give parameter.

Comment: I have written the  the approach to create a global function.

Comment: Extending `NSObject` doesn't add the method to all Swift classes.  It also doesn't add it to structs like `String`, `Array`, `Dictionary`, etc.

Comment: @nhgrif you are right, it doesn't add to structs directly like String, Array, Dictionary but these are  primary collection types  but In context about the whole Swift Application, Most of the classes are based on the NSObject class Like Whole UIKit, CoreLocation, MapKit and many more so It'll work.

Comment: Stuff that comes from Objective-C inherits from `NSObject`.  Code we write in pure Swift that does not inherit from Objective-C objects should not themselves be inheriting from `NSObject`.  But it doesn't matter, because that extension doesn't even make sense.